# Sum of Binomial random variable CDF

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Suppose there are two independent Binomial random variables
$$
X\sim Binomial(n,p)\\
Y\sim Binomial(n,p+\delta)
$$
where $\delta$ is considered to be fixed, and $p$ can vary in $(0,1-\delta)$.

Now consider the following value (sum of two probabilities):
$$
\mathbb{P} \left( X\geq(p+\frac{\delta}2)\cdot n \right)
+\mathbb{P} \left( Y\leq(p+\frac{\delta}2)\cdot n \right)
$$

My question is: Which value of $p$ maximizes the above quantity?
My intuition and simulation both says that when $p+\frac{\delta}2=1/2$, the value takes its maximum. It seems to be a very easy problem, but I could not prove it. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Let's suppose that $n$ is even, so that we can have an integer as threshold when $p=(1-\delta)/2$.

Comment: We get the same value for $p'=1-\delta-p$ instead of $p$, i.e. the graph is symmetric with respect to $p=\frac{1-\delta}{2}$. What would be sufficient to prove is that there are no more local minimizers. I guess we have convexity.

Comment: $p=(1-\delta)/2$ cannot possibly be right for odd $n$ because then $(p+\delta/2)n$ is not an integer, and modifying $p$ so that you hit one of the adjacent integers is an obvious improvement.

Comment: @MarkusSprecher Thanks for the comment. (1) That 's right, the quantity is symmetric w.r.t $p=\frac{1-\delta}2$. (2) Actually we don't have convexity in this case, an obvious reason would be that when $(p+\delta/2\cdot n)$ is an integer, the quantity would be discontinuous

Comment: @ChristianRemling, thanks for the comment! You're right, what if $n$ is assumed to be even? Do you have any ideas for proving this?

Comment: I think "tail probabilities" is the technical term for what you're looking at here. See for example this paper by our own @BrendanMcKay, who may be able to say something useful about this: https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/littlewood2.pdf

Comment: Also, if you just apply the CLT (for large $n$), even though it doesn't really apply (you're many standard deviations from the expected value), the formulae suggest that you want $p\simeq 1/2$ or $p+\delta\simeq 1/2$. I'm not sure though if this reasoning makes much sense.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for the reply! (1) It's a very good note! However some exact arguments are needed here, so the approximations of the tail probability/ bounds of the CDF might not be very useful here. (2) When CLT is applied, the problem gets simplified significantly, however in my application, both big $n$ and small $n$ cases have to be considered and proved.

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, this won't help for general $n$, I meant it more as a test on your conjecture.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a global maximum here it might depend on what values $\delta$ can have say for example $\delta$ is close to zero than both $p=1$ and $p=0$ are close to two (the maximum value ) if $\delta=0$ the expression above becomes equal to 2 for both $p=0$ and $p=1$ independent of n. However $p=(1-\delta)/2$ is not equal to two 2. (it will be somewhere around 1). therefore I conjecture that a global optimum depends on the value of $\delta$